# Thumbnail Gallery CSS and Jquery issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, gallery, image-gallery

I have already had a hunt through the site to see if I can find an answer but unfortunately I cannot find one - my issue is quite specific so I'm hoping someone can help.

I have built a gallery with thumbnails which you can see at the link below. I built this from a tutorial I found online as I'm not that great with Jquery yet. I had to amend the size of the large image and thumbnails from the tutorial code and since doing that it hasn't quite lined up how I would like. I amended the sizes in CSS only as instructed in the tutorial.

My issue is: The thumbnail block on images does not line up nicely with the bottom of the large image. It looks like it cuts off. I have checked every aspect of the CSS, which I have pasted below.

Many thanks in advance for taking a look.

http://www.emmasteed.co.uk/robsteed/gallery.html

```
#slideshow-main {
    width:714px; 
    float:left; 
    margin-right:3px;
}

#slideshow-main ul {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    width:714px;
}

#slideshow-main li {
    width:714px; 
    height:351px; 
    display:none;
    position:relative;
}

#slideshow-main li.active {
    display:block !important;
}

#slideshow-main li span.opacity {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; left:0;
    display:block; 
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:#000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
    -moz-opacity:0.5; 
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5; 
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index:500;
}

#slideshow-main li span.content {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; left:0;
    display:block; 
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    z-index:1000;
}

#slideshow-main li span.content h1 {
    font-size:14px;
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:0 10px;;
    color:#42e2e8;
}

#slideshow-main li span.content p {
    font-size:11px;
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:0 10px;;
    color:#42e2e8;
}

#slideshow-carousel {
    float:left;
    width:206px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
}

#slideshow-carousel ul {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

#slideshow-carousel li {
    background:#fff; 
    height:117px; 
    position:relative
}

#slideshow-carousel li .arrow {
    left:3px; 
    top:38px; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:20px; 
    height:40px; 
    background:url(images/arrow_white.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
    display:block;
}

#slideshow-carousel li a {
    background:#000; 
    display:block; 
    width:206px; 
    height:117px;
}


#slideshow-carousel .active {
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
    -moz-opacity:1.0; 
    -khtml-opacity: 1.0; 
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#slideshow-carousel .faded {
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
    -moz-opacity:0.5; 
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5; 
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height of `.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-vertical` to match the height of the slider.

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-vertical {
    height: 351px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realised that there was a separate CSS that I needed to amend. Well spotted - thanks!